# If statement issue not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to see if a lat and long that is entered corresponds with one of two types of polygons either one with a key of Live and one with a key of Soon, however I cant seem to get the if statement write.

So if a lat + long point is in a polygon type Live the result should be, Location is found and is live. If a lat + long point is in a polygon type Soon the result should be, Location is found and is coming soon. If the lat + long does not reside in a polygon the result should be, Location is not found.

What am I doing wrong with my if statement?

```
initGeocompleteControl(map, function (result) {
    map.data.forEach(function (f) {
        if (f.getProperty("key") == "live") {

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            calcBounds(f.getGeometry(), bounds);

            if (bounds.contains(result.geometry.location)) {
                $( "#result" ).empty();
                $("#result").html('Location is found and is live');
            } else if (f.getProperty("key") == "soon") {
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                calcBounds(f.getGeometry(), bounds);

                if (bounds.contains(result.geometry.location)) {
                    $( "#result" ).empty();
                    $("#result").html('Location is found and is coming soon');
                } else {
                    $( "#result" ).empty();
                    $("#result").html('Location is not found');
                }
              //w11 2ed
            }
          // w10 5nr
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: *Which* `if` statement? You have four of them.

Comment: Aligning your code properly shows the problem; your `else if (f.getProperty("key") == "soon")` statement is one level too deep.  See my edit of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your else if condition outside ie. outside of `if(f.getProperty("key"...`

```
initGeocompleteControl(map, function (result) {
map.data.forEach(function (f) {

    if (f.getProperty("key") == "live") {

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        calcBounds(f.getGeometry(), bounds);

        if (bounds.contains(result.geometry.location)) {
            $( "#result" ).empty();
            $("#result").html('Location is found and is live');
        }
        //the else if moved from here
    }
    else if
          (f.getProperty("key") == "soon") {

              var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
              calcBounds(f.getGeometry(), bounds);

              if (bounds.contains(result.geometry.location)) {
                  $( "#result" ).empty();
                  $("#result").html('Location is found and is coming soon');
              } 
              //else condition moved from here
          } //and else condition after the else if condtion
          else {
                  $( "#result" ).empty();
                  $("#result").html('Location is not found');
          }
              //w11 2ed

          // w10 5nr
     }); 
});
```

Comment: For some reason it wont ever iterate to the last else. Any ideas why?